# Using @Autowired for invoking a class to test for a Junit case

Tags: java, spring, junit, junit4

```
@Autowired
BookUtil bookUtil;

@Before
pub void setUp(){
}

@Test
pub void testLogin(){
String userName = "Harry";
String password = "1234";
bookUtil = new BookUtil();
bookUtil.checkuserNamePassword (userName, password);
}
```

This gives me a null pointer exception for bookUtil.I am using Junit4 to run this test case in a spring-portlet application.However, if I make the following change i.e. create the object for the bookUtil manually it works fine.

Comment: Show us the whole class, not just the methods and fields

Comment: Also, I'd like to see bean configuration file where you registered bookUtil bean, or it's class if it's component (autoscan) or Javaconfig code.

Answer (score 1):

Make correct use of the the [Spring Test Framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html), specifically ["Dependency Injection of test fixtures"](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-fixture-di). I.e. you need to annotate the class properly:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("your-context.xml")
class MyTest {
    @Autowired
    BookUtil bookUtil;
    ...
}
```